# Not able to exclude some rules from PMD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pmd

I'm just trying to add PMD to my Spring Boot project but I'm facing some issues trying to exclude some rules from `category/java/errorprone.xml` ruleset.

I'm using the gradle plugin as follows:

```
pmd {
    ruleSetConfig = resources.text.fromFile("config/pmd/ruleset.xml")
}
```

and this is the content of my custom ruleset file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset>
    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml"></rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/codestyle.xml">
        <exclude name="MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal"/>
        <exclude name="LocalVariableCouldBeFinal"/>
        <exclude name="ControlStatementBraces"/>
        <exclude name="OnlyOneReturn"/>
        <exclude name="ConfusingTernary"/>
        <exclude name="AtLeastOneConstructor"/>
        <exclude name="AvoidFinalLocalVariable"/>
        <exclude name="ShortVariable"/>
        <exclude name="LongVariable"/>
        <exclude name="CommentDefaultAccessModifier"/>
        <exclude name="DefaultPackage"/>
        <exclude name="PrematureDeclaration"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/design.xml">
        <exclude name="LawOfDemeter"/>
        <exclude name="NcssCount"/>
        <exclude name="CyclomaticComplexity"/>
        <exclude name="UseUtilityClass"/>
        <exclude name="AvoidCatchingGenericException"/>
        <exclude name="NPathComplexity"/>
        <exclude name="AvoidRethrowingException"/>
        <exclude name="DataClass"/>
        <exclude name="AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/documentation.xml">
        <exclude name="CommentRequired"/>
        <exclude name="UncommentedEmptyConstructor"/>
        <exclude name="CommentSize"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml">
        <exclude name="BeanMembersShouldSerialize"/>
        <exclude name="DataflowAnomalyAnalysis"/>
        <exclude name="AssignmentInOperand"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/multithreading.xml">
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/performance.xml">
        <exclude name="AvoidInstantiatingObjectsInLoops"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/security.xml">
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

As you can see there, I'm excluding both `BeanMembersShouldSerialize`and `DataflowAnomalyAnalysis` but I'm still getting these errors in the PMD report:

`Found non-transient, non-static member. Please mark as transient or provide accessors.`

`Found 'DU'-anomaly for variable 'userEntity' (lines '28'-'38').``

I'm using PMD version 6.10.0 (December 9th 2018).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gradle defaults to using the `basic` and `braces` rulesets up to Gradle 5. Gradle 5 defaults to using the `errorprone` category.

You need to clear out these defaults if you don't want them by doing:

```
pmd {
    ruleSets = [] 
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Pmd.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Pmd:ruleSets

Comment: Wow! That works as a charm! I didn't know that. Thank you again, you saved my day